# why is this flex-wrap child increasing the parent width and how to prevent?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have created a Codepen with this issue:
https://codepen.io/antoniandre/pen/wvGWmXO?editors=1100

How can I keep the label and input on the same line and put the span on the next line within the same wrapper using display flex and flex wrap without increasing the width of the parent container (which is in absolute position)?

```
div
  label label
  input(type="text")
  span This is fine

input(id="checkbox" type="checkbox") 
label(for="checkbox") Hide span

div
  label label
  input(type="text")
  span This is pushing
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #fcf;
  padding: 10px;
}

div ~ div {
  top: 120px;

  span {flex: 1 0 100%;}
}
:checked ~ div span {display: none;}
```

I have read a few questions about that but no helping me.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

- I can't set a width, the box it's in must fit to the content.
- The input field must fill the available space on the first line, hence the `display: flex`.

Answer (score 1):

The result can be achieved by using flex and also without it.

**With Flex**
Set the width of the parent container and you're done.

```
div
  label label
  input(type="text")
  span This is fine

input(id="checkbox" type="checkbox") 
label(for="checkbox") Hide span

div
  label label
  input(type="text")
  span This is pushing
```

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #fcf;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 223px; /* Set this accordingly */
}

div ~ div {
  top: 120px;

  span {flex: 1 0 100%;}
}
:checked ~ div span {display: none;}
```

**Without Flex**
Using `::before` pseudo-element, we can insert line break before every span tags.

```
div
  label label
  input(type="text")
  span This is fine

input(id="checkbox" type="checkbox") 
label(for="checkbox") Hide span

div
  label label
  input(type="text")
  span This is pushing
```

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #fcf;
  padding: 10px;
  
  span {
    &::before {
      content: '\A';
      white-space: pre;
    }
  }
}

div ~ div {
  top: 120px;
}

:checked ~ div span {display: none;}
```

Comment: As per my question, the span should stay on a new line. so this is not helping. Any other idea?

Comment: @antoni I'm extremely sorry! I updated my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @ava, unfortunately I can't set a width as the box it's in must have its width fitting the content whatever the content is. And I also need the input to fill the available space so I need the flex display. But Today I learnt you can put `\A` in a pseudo element, that was smart thanks for that! +1

Comment: @antoni without having any definite width using flexbox, I don't think it's possible to achieve what you want. The flex items need to be wrapped to go to the new line. So for this very specific problem, I think CSS Grid should be the go-to approach.